# How can I use Media Query in PHP?

Tags: php, css, media

How can I use Media Queries in PHP?
I already have a Code but the problem is that the design doesn't change when  you change the size of the window. Is there a possible way?

```
        <?php
      if (isset($_GET['width'])) {
        $width = $_GET['width'];
        if ($width <= 800) { //mobile devices
          $style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="mobile.css" type="text/css">';
        } else { //desktop
          $style = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">';
        }
        echo $style;
      } else {
          echo "<script language='javascript'>\n";
          echo "  location.href=\"${_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']}?${_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']}" . "&width=\" + screen.width; \n";
          echo "</script>\n";
          exit();
      }
    ?>
```

Comment: Can you refresh window after resize ?

Comment: How do you pass the width via get parameter to php? FYI, you can use media queries without php, because browser detects device details for you. Have a look at Davids answer ;)

Comment: @JaydeepMor No.. It always takes the width of the original screen (Example: 1920px)

Comment: media queries have nothing to do with php. You actually make them in css, and browser will take care of screen width and everything. see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 2):

I don't see how this could work since PHP runs before the browser width is determined. However it's not necessary anyways. What you want to do is apply the media query to the link element.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (max-width: 800px)" href="mobile.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-width: 801px)" href="style.css"/>
```

Comment: Interesting. I'm not sure wether or not I like this better than plain media queries inside a stylesheet. You might want to add details about compatibility, this is not universally supported.

Comment: The idea here is to load a resource based on the mq. If you have the mq inside the file it has already been loaded. I'm not certain however, if this triggers a roundtrip to the server. I personally prefer one heavily optimised file

Comment: It could be that someone asking the same question wants to add code (besides styling) depending on the device and wants to know if there is any way other than detecting wether mobile/desktop.

Answer (score 2):

PHP is executed before page is rendered. If you are aiming for a more dynamic behavior I would suggest using JS. Something more like this:

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    ...
});
```

or in Vanilla JS

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    ...
};
```

With this you can actually load/unload the CSS files you've mentioned.

My recommendation though is to rely just in a good (and only) CSS file having all your media queries in there.

[Responsive Web Design - Media Queries](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)